# Install older version of gfortran in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, compiler

I want to install 4.8.4 gfortran compiler in my Ubuntu 16.04.
I tried this

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran-4.8.4
```

but it returns

```
unable to locate package
```

Answer (score 1):

The `E: Unable to locate package gfortran-4.8.4` error message means exactly what it says. There is no package named gfortran-4.8.4 in Ubuntu 16.04. The closest match in 16.04 is gfortran-4.8 which installs gfortran version 4.8.5, not 4.8.4.

In Ubuntu 14.04 the command `sudo apt install gfortran-4.8` installs gfortran version 4.8.4. You could install an Ubuntu 14.04 guest OS in VirtualBox and run gfortran 4.8.4 that way. Before you do it try installing gfortran 4.8.5 in Ubuntu 16.04 with the command `sudo apt install gfortran-4.8` and test if it can do what you need it to do.